# colorbox & requirejs, colorbox not working but no error displayed

Tags: jquery, requirejs, colorbox

i'm new to use requirejs and would like to using jquery plugin, here is my example:

app.html

```js
//app.js


// Place third party dependencies in the lib folder
//
// Configure loading modules from the lib directory,
// except 'app' ones, 
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "js/lib",
    "paths": {
      "app": "../app",
      "colorbox": "colorbox"
    },
    "shim": {
        "colorbox": { deps: ["jquery"], exports: "colorbox" }
    }
});

// Load the main app module to start the app

requirejs(["app/page"]);



//page.js
require(["jquery", "colorbox"],function($){ //import the jquery script 
    $(function(){
        $("#button_1").click(function(){
            // alert("button_1 got a click");
            console.log("before!");
            $(".vimeo").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:500, innerHeight:409});
            console.log("after!");
        });
    });
});
```

i have used shim and export for the non-AMD colorbox plugin, and in the source part i have found colorbox.js is loaded. but it is not working, thanks for any tipps.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery+RequireJS Sample Page</title>
        <script data-main="js/app" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>jQuery+RequireJS Sample Page</h1>
        <p>Look at source or inspect the DOM to see how it works.</p>
        <button id="button_1">sup</button>
        <p><a class='vimeo' href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/2285902" title="R&ouml;yksopp: Remind Me">Flash / Video (Iframe/Direct Link To Vimeo)</a></p>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: above is the html part.